# how to use fetch to post data to php

Tags: javascript, php, fetch, nativescript

i'm trying to create a comment function for my nativescript app, using the link on my brwser, this functionality works fine. but using the fetch API in my app, it returns the error function (error message is unexpected token < in JSON at position 0)

```
function AddCommentViewModel() {
      const viewModel = observableModule.fromObject({});
      var comm = "nice guy";
      var email = appSettings.getString("email");
      var phone = appSettings.getString("number");
        alert(comm);
        alert(email);
        alert(phone);
        var url = "https://adekunletestprojects.000webhostapp.com/skog/addComment.php?email" + email + "&number=" + phone + "&comment=" + comm;
        fetch(url).then((response) => response.json()).then((res) => {
    viewModel.set("itemsd", res.itemss);
            alert("successful");
     }).catch((err) => {
            alert("failed");
    });
      return viewModel;
    }
```

my php is

```
<?php 

include 'config.php';
$number = $_GET['number'];
$comment = $_GET['comment'];
$email = $_GET['email'];
try {
    $dbh = new PDO("mysql:host=$dbhost;dbname=$dbname", $dbuser, $dbpass);
    $sql = "SELECT name FROM searchResults WHERE email='$email'";
    $dbh->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
    $stmt = $dbh->prepare($sql);  
    //$stmt->bindParam(":email", $_GET['email']);
    $stmt->execute();
    $employees = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    $employees1 = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
    $name = $employees['name'];
    $sql1 = "INSERT INTO comments (number, comment, user, date) VALUES ('$number', '$comment', '$name', '02/04/2020')";
    $sth = $dbh->query($sql1);
    $sth->execute();
    $dbh = null; 
    echo '{"itemss":'. json_encode($employees1) .'}';
    //$conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$dbhost;dbname=$dbname", $dbuser, $dbpass);
} catch(PDOException $e) {
    echo '{"error":{"text":'. $e->getMessage() .'}}'; 
}

?>
```

Comment: Well, _which_ error? Start by checking the contents of `err`.

Comment: what exact error do you get? Did you check? P.S. `echo '{"itemss":'. json_encode($employees1) .'}';` is a bad way to generate json. Instead write `$output = array ("itemss" => $employees1); echo json_encode($output);`. Same principle when you echo the exception message: `$output = array("error" => array("text" => $e->getMessage())); echo json_encode($output);`. Never generate JSON manually.

Comment: @CherryDT error message is unexpected token < in JSON at position 0

Comment: So there is HTML instead of JSON. Use `response.text()` instead of `response.json()` and then print what `res` you got, so you can see the actual contents before you fail parsing them as JSON. (Ideally you'd use a debugging proxy to see what is actually going over the line.)

Comment: oh I spotted something else - writing an answer, sec

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error `Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0` most likely means that you got HTML back instead of JSON. (Imagine parsing `<html>.....` as JSON - then the first character is `<` which is not valid JSON.)

You can temporarily use `response.text()` instead of `response.json()` and then print what `res` you got, so you can see the actual contents before you fail parsing them as JSON. (Ideally you'd use a debugging proxy to see what is actually going over the line, or just use [DevTools](https://docs.nativescript.org/tooling/debugging/chrome-devtools) and look at the network tab!)

I'd assume that your server shows an error, and it shows it as HTML.

Actually, I spotted another issue in your code, which may be the reason for your invalid request:

```js
var url = "https://adekunletestprojects.000webhostapp.com/skog/addComment.php?email" + email + "&number=" + phone + "&comment=" + comm;
```

The code here has `"?email" + email` which will generate something like `?emailjohn@doe.com`, which is probably not what you want. You are missing an equal sign here: `"?email=" + email`

But this has another problem, you are not encoding the values. What if the email is set to `john&alice=bob@doe.com`? Then you'll have `?email=john&alice=bob@doe.com` which you don't want either. (Or imagine a *comment text* containing `&`, which is more likely.)

If this were in a browser or node.js, you'd best use the `URL` object, but in NativeScript you don't have that. So, you'd just use `encodeURIComponent` to encode each individual value:

```js
var url = "https://adekunletestprojects.000webhostapp.com/skog/addComment.php?email=" +
  encodeURIComponent(email) + "&number=" + encodeURIComponent(phone) + "&comment=" +
  encodeURIComponent(comm);
```

Or, you could write a helper function to do it for you, and get cleaner code:

```js
const buildQuery = params => Object.entries(params)
  .map(([k, v]) => `${k}=${encodeURIComponent(v)}`)
  .join('&')

// Later on:
const query = buildQuery({ email: email, number: phone, comment: comm })
const url = `https://adekunletestprojects.000webhostapp.com/skog/addComment.php?${query}`
```

Comment: oh my God!, thanks so much. been looking at that line for like an hour, didn't notice the sign was missing @CherryDT

Comment: You are welcome :) a tip though: looking at the request would have helped. check out [this link](https://docs.nativescript.org/tooling/debugging/chrome-devtools), then next time you could just look into the "network" tab to see both request and response, and you'd notice a) the HTML coming back and its contents, and b) the bad request data

Comment: your suggestion says URL is not defined, please

Comment: Hm, you are right, NativeScript doesn't have the `URL` object. I'm amending my answer.

Comment: Updated :) sorry about that.